# Disable "go to parent class" triangle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-indigo

In Eclipse Indigo, there's this little triangle next to an overriding method in a Java editor that, when clicked, will take you to the overridden method definition.  It just so happens to be right on top of the area you click to add breakpoints, which I do much more frequently than something easily accomplished by ctrl-click.

I've looked around, and can't figure out what the name of this feature is, or how to turn it off. Any ideas?

This is the misbehaving button in question:

[image: Eclipse's "go to parent declaration" button]

Comment: Instead of clicking to add a breakpoint you can use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an editor annotation.

In Juno at least you can turn them off from your preferences in General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations, untick show in vertical ruler:
[image: Eclipse Preferences on Mac]